# gedit use of file not showing in fuser

Tags: linux, operating-system, fuser

I have started using the fuser command and it looks very useful. It seems to work well. However I noticed a little anomaly which is that if I open a file with gedit fuser doesn't tell me that gedit has accessed that file. It shows all the other processes I have tested it with, including scripts etc.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 if that makes any difference.

Why would it not show gedit? And is there a way I can get around this problem?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fuser is only going to show files that are currently open.  Many editors don't leave the file open.  They open it, read it, then close it.  So when you run fuser on that file it doesn't show anything because it's not currently open.